# Autosave to a text file with the timer

Tags: vb.net, autosave

I have created a "Save Button", a "timer", a "savefiledialog1"

I have written the following code for those.

Code For "Save Button" is...

```
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

Code For the "Savefiledialog1" is...

```
Dim FileToSaveAs As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FileToSaveAs)
    objwriter.Write(Textbox1.Text)
    Timer1.Start()
    objwriter.Close()
```

and the Code For "timer" is...

```
Dim FileToSaveAs As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FileToSaveAs)
    objwriter.Write(Textbox1.Text)
    objwriter.Write("")
    objwriter.Write(Textbox2.Text)
    objwriter.Write("")
    objwriter.Write(Textbox3.Text)
    objwriter.Write("")
objwriter.Close()
```

My problem is when i run the application, and enter values in all 3 Textboxes, The Autosave is working fine but There are no line breaks in the output and all the data is combined, which is even very hard to read.

**What's going wrong here ???**

Comment: replace `objWriter.Write()` with `objWriter.WriteLine()`

Comment: Thanks a lot Man... Sometimes small things trouble us a lot ;)